# SQL - Convert String to Date and compare - Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I currently have dates stored in a general attribute field in the database as a string.

They are all stored in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` for example `01/01/2000`

I am able to convert them them to `datetime` successfully by using the following in my `select` statement. For example `CONVERT(DATETIME, attribute.field_value, 103)` where `attribute.field_value` contains a date.

The `SELECT` statement works fine and returns the whole table with them correctly.

I can also return a column with todays date in the same format as follows `CAST(getdate() AS datetime)`

The problem occurs when I try to compare, now I only want to return everything that is newer than today in pseudo code that would `dateNewerThanToday > dateToday`

Therefore I have tried
`WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, attribute.field_value, 103) > CAST(getdate() AS datetime)`

this gives me the error

`Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.`

I have tried a multitude of cast/converts to get it to work. I have also wrapped by select so I am only doing it on dataset with the correct data.

Any help would be super useful! Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is there any chance that one of the row of `attribute.field_value` column contains non convert able value. Try firing `Select CONVERT(DATETIME, attribute.field_value, 103) from attribute` and see if this works.

Comment: Definitely sounds like one of your dates is not in the correct format

Comment: OP states that the `CONVERT` does work in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things ..

1. You do not need to convert to `GETDATE()` to `DATETIME data type` as it  already returns datetime data type.
2. Instead of `CONVERT(DATETIME, attribute.field_value, 103)`

   use

   `CONVERT(DATETIME, attribute.field_value)` or `CAST(attribute.field_value AS DATETIME)`
3. Add a where clause in your select to get only valid `DATETIME` values. something like

   `WHERE ISDATE(attribute.field_value) = 1`

   This will filter out any values which appears to be a date value but sql server doesnt see them as valid date values.

**Important Not**

Use appropriate data types. If this column is storing date values why not use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types.

Comment: Better late than never to accept. While this was a little while back and I haven't tested it. Since then my skills have grown and I can see this would in theory work nicely. Thanks for your assistance many years ago!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem.

Values from a `VARCHAR(50)` column returned in the `SELECT` could be cast as date without issue. However when cast in a comparison in the WHERE clause the error occurred.

Of note, the error only occurred when I had other restrictions in the `WHERE` clause.

When I added `ISDATE()` to the `WHERE` clause, the error no longer occurred.

e.g. Shortened example of what worked:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, mat.myAttributeColumn), mdct.myDateComparisonColumn
    FROM myAttributeTable mat
    JOIN myDateComparisonTable mdct ON mdct.key = mat.key
    WHERE ISDATE(mat.myAttributeColumn) = 1
    and mdct.myDateComparisonColumn < convert(DATE, mat.myAttributeColumn)
```